# ¿Por qué una función recursiva no me devuelve valor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, recursión

He estado haciendo un código mucho más grande y tras comprobar uno de los componentes por separado he conseguido aislar el error en una función.

Al parecer la función no me hace return como debiera, y por ende no me deja obtener un valor en la misma. Me parece extraño y no entiendo, la verdad, dónde podría estar el susodicho error. Lo hemos visto entre tres pero nada.

Simplemente es una función para pedir un string y limitar el nombre

```
import re

def limit_name(nombre=None,campo="del campo"):
    # Limitamos a que sean Str.
    if nombre == None:
        # raise ValueError("Se necesita un Identificador")
        # print("Se necesita un identificador")
        nombre = str(input("Deme el valor {}\t".format(campo))) # Como Wildcar para que nos varien los datos. Ya no tendríamos que pedirlos en un print previo si no quisiésemos.
        limit_name(nombre)
    else: # Como ya redefinido no es "none".
        try:
            str(nombre)
        except ValueError:
            ValueError("No pasable a str")

        nombre = str(nombre)
        if "," in nombre:
            # raise ValueError("El valor de 'Nombre' no puede tener comas") # No queremos errores, sino que funcione.
            print("El valor no puede tener comas. Probemos de nuevo")
            # Volvemos a llamar a la función.
            limit_name()
        elif nombre.startswith((" ", ".", "\t", "\n")):
            # raise ValueError("¿Por qué iba a empezar por un espacio, o por un punto?")
            print("¿Por qué iba a empezar por un espacio, o por un punto? Prueba otra vez")
            limit_name()
        elif (len(nombre) > 50) | (len(nombre) == 0):  # Debería estar cubierto con None. Pero por si acaso.
            # raise ValueError("El nombre es demasiado largo o de longitud 0. Prueba uno más corto.")
            print("Es demasiado largo o de longitud 0. Prueba uno más corto")
            limit_name()
        else:
            patron = r'^([\s\d]+)$'  # Que no sean completmaente numerico/num-espacios.
            if  (re.match(patron, nombre)): ### Si lo son, tenemos que confirmar para esto.

                seguir = str(input("El identificador solo contiene números. ¿Continuamos? Sí para seguir."))
                if seguir in ["Si", "si", "s", "Y", "y", "yes", "Yes", "True", True]:
                    nombre = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", nombre)  # Substituimos esto.
                    nombre = nombre.strip()  # Quitamos el inicial y final.
                    print(type(nombre))
                    return nombre  # ya es st
                else:
                    print("Probemos de nuevo.,,")
                    limit_name()

            else:
                print("Identificador adecuado.\n Sustituiremos las posibles tabulaciones y posibles saltos por espacios,\n y borraremos los espacios iniciales y finales")
                nombre = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", nombre) #Substituimos esto.
                nombre = nombre.strip() #Quitamos el inicial y final.
                print(type(nombre))
                print(nombre)


                return nombre  # ya es str

e = limit_name(None)

print(e)

print(e)
```

Output:

```
    Deme el valor del campo asdf
    Identificador adecuado.
     Sustituiremos las posibles tabulaciones y posibles saltos por espacios,
     y borraremos los espacios iniciales y finales
    <class 'str'>
    asdf
    None
```

Y claro, no entiendo por qué pasa esto.

ACTUALIZACION

Encontrado el fallo del indent del return:

```
import re

def limit_name(nombre=None,campo="del campo"):
    # Limitamos a que sean Str.
    if nombre == None:
        # raise ValueError("Se necesita un Identificador")
        # print("Se necesita un identificador")
        nombre = str(input("Deme el valor {}\t".format(campo))) # Como Wildcar para que nos varien los datos. Ya no tendríamos que pedirlos en un print previo si no quisiésemos.
        limit_name(nombre)
    else: # Como ya redefinido no es "none".
        try:
            str(nombre)
        except ValueError:
            ValueError("No pasable a str")

        nombre = str(nombre)
        if "," in nombre:
            # raise ValueError("El valor de 'Nombre' no puede tener comas") # No queremos errores, sino que funcione.
            print("El valor no puede tener comas. Probemos de nuevo")
            # Volvemos a llamar a la función.
            limit_name()
        elif nombre.startswith((" ", ".", "\t", "\n")):
            # raise ValueError("¿Por qué iba a empezar por un espacio, o por un punto?")
            print("¿Por qué iba a empezar por un espacio, o por un punto? Prueba otra vez")
            limit_name()
        elif (len(nombre) > 50) | (len(nombre) == 0):  # Debería estar cubierto con None. Pero por si acaso.
            # raise ValueError("El nombre es demasiado largo o de longitud 0. Prueba uno más corto.")
            print("Es demasiado largo o de longitud 0. Prueba uno más corto")
            limit_name()
        else:
            patron = r'^([\s\d]+)$'  # Que no sean completmaente numerico/num-espacios.
            if  (re.match(patron, nombre)): ### Si lo son, tenemos que confirmar para esto.

                seguir = str(input("El identificador solo contiene números. ¿Continuamos? Sí para seguir."))
                if seguir in ["Si", "si", "s", "Y", "y", "yes", "Yes", "True", True]:
                    nombre = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", nombre)  # Substituimos esto.
                    nombre = nombre.strip()  # Quitamos el inicial y final.
                    print(type(nombre))
                    # return nombre  # ya es st
                else:
                    print("Probemos de nuevo.,,")
                    limit_name()

            else:
                print("Identificador adecuado.\n Sustituiremos las posibles tabulaciones y posibles saltos por espacios,\n y borraremos los espacios iniciales y finales")
                nombre = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", nombre) #Substituimos esto.
                nombre = nombre.strip() #Quitamos el inicial y final.
                print(type(nombre))
                print(nombre)

    return nombre            # return nombre  # ya es str

e = limit_name(None)

print(e)
```

```
Deme el valor del campo asdfasf,asdfsadf
El valor no puede tener comas. Probemos de nuevo
Deme el valor del campo campo
Identificador adecuado.
 Sustituiremos las posibles tabulaciones y posibles saltos por espacios,
 y borraremos los espacios iniciales y finales
<class 'str'>
campo
asdfasf,asdfsadf
```

Cuando lo que me interesa es que me devuelva el corregido.

Comment: La solución va como respuesta  y no en la pregunta, por favor colócala donde corresponde y tampoco es necesario le colocas SOLUCIONADO, con tener una respuesta aceptada alcanza

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, lo había puesto como solución sin el solucionado, pero me borraron la respuesta. La he vuelto a subir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dice:

```
def limit_name(nombre=None,campo="del campo"):
    # Limitamos a que sean Str.
    if nombre == None:

            # Código irrelevante.

            else:
                print("Identificador adecuado.\n Sustituiremos las posibles tabulaciones y posibles saltos por espacios,\n y borraremos los espacios iniciales y finales")
                nombre = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", nombre) #Substituimos esto.
                nombre = nombre.strip() #Quitamos el inicial y final.
                print(type(nombre))
                print(nombre)


                return nombre  # ya es str
```

La sangría del `return` es incorrecta. Tiene que estar más afuera. Tal como la escribiste, el `return` se ejecuta sólo si llega al último else.
Debe decir:

```
def limit_name(nombre=None,campo="del campo"):
    # Limitamos a que sean Str.

    # Todo el codigo entremedio borrado.

    return nombre  # ya es str
    ^
----+
```

Comment: Gracias. No sabes cuántas horas le he echado a esto y no sabía por qué no era así.

Comment: ¿Y si quisiera, por ejemplo, devolver uno u otro valor según se cumpliesen uno u otro if? No deberían ir dentro para que me pudiera hacer un return condicionado? Es decir, en mi código llega hasta el ultimo Else, pero no devuelve el return.

Comment: @Galpaccru. Tienes dos opciones: 1) cambiar el valor dentro del if y retornarlo al final;  2) Retornar en medio de un if, tan pronto tengas el valor que deseas. Es más claro y conveniente tener un sólo retorno al final.

Comment: Pero mira por ejemplo lo que me pasa ahora (actualizo pregunta). Que no me devuelve el valor final sino el inicial si no cumple los valores. Y creo que necesito el mismo nombre para poder rellamar a la función, digo yo. @Candid Moe

Comment: Añadido por qué fallaba. Cosas de recursividad y el tener que hacerle return a la propia recursión.

Answer (score 1):

Di con el error.

Al parecer cuando se utiliza una recursión (llamamiento a la misma función) debe ponerse el return(funcion_recursion) para que así continúe guardando y retornando el valor como output. Fallaba porque no había un return inicial, y por ende daba None, incapaz de guardar el continuo flujo de returns pues se perdía el primero (al meter el return en la recursividad, se va actualizando el valor y sí permite obtener la respuesta).

Queda así pues:

````
import re

def limit_name(nombre=None,campo="del campo"):
    # Limitamos a que sean Str.
    if nombre == None:
        # raise ValueError("Se necesita un Identificador")
        # print("Se necesita un identificador")
        nombre = str(input("Deme el valor {}\t".format(campo))) # Como Wildcar para que nos varien los datos. Ya no tendríamos que pedirlos en un print previo si no quisiésemos.
        return(limit_name(nombre))
    else: # Como ya redefinido no es "none".
        try:
            str(nombre)
        except ValueError:
            ValueError("No pasable a str")

        nombre = str(nombre)
        if "," in nombre:
            # raise ValueError("El valor de 'Nombre' no puede tener comas") # No queremos errores, sino que funcione.
            print("El valor no puede tener comas. Probemos de nuevo")
            # Volvemos a llamar a la función.
            return(limit_name())
        elif nombre.startswith((" ", ".", "\t", "\n")):
            # raise ValueError("¿Por qué iba a empezar por un espacio, o por un punto?")
            print("¿Por qué iba a empezar por un espacio, o por un punto? Prueba otra vez")
            return(limit_name())
        elif (len(nombre) > 50) | (len(nombre) == 0):  # Debería estar cubierto con None. Pero por si acaso.
            # raise ValueError("El nombre es demasiado largo o de longitud 0. Prueba uno más corto.")
            print("Es demasiado largo o de longitud 0. Prueba uno más corto")
            return(limit_name())
        else:
            patron = r'^([\s\d]+)$'  # Que no sean completmaente numerico/num-espacios.
            if  (re.match(patron, nombre)): ### Si lo son, tenemos que confirmar para esto.

                seguir = str(input("El identificador solo contiene números. ¿Continuamos? Sí para seguir."))
                if seguir in ["Si", "si", "s", "Y", "y", "yes", "Yes", "True", True]:
                    nombre = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", nombre)  # Substituimos esto.
                    nombre = nombre.strip()  # Quitamos el inicial y final.
                    print(type(nombre))
                    return(nombre)
                else:
                    print("Probemos de nuevo.,,")
                    return(limit_name())

            else:
                print("Identificador adecuado.\n Sustituiremos las posibles tabulaciones y posibles saltos por espacios,\n y borraremos los espacios iniciales y finales")
                nombre = re.sub("\s\s+", " ", nombre) #Substituimos esto.
                nombre = nombre.strip() #Quitamos el inicial y final.
                print(type(nombre))
                print(nombre)
                return(nombre)

```
````